# How to remove ?___from_store=default from other store code url of my magento 2 website?

Tags: multistore, magento2.2.2, store-view

I have 2 stores on my Magento 2 website.
one for Srilanka & the other for Australia.
I am redirecting my customers based on customer's IPs to relevant sores.
Whenever I am redirecting the customer to an Australian store, I am getting the URL like below

```
https://staging.mywebsite.lk/aus/?___from_store=default
```

After going through the product page and category pages URL is appearing without `/?___from_store=default`

I tried 302 redirects using htaccess file like below.  But no luck.

**Redirect 301 /aus/?___from_store=default https://staging.mywebsite.lk/aus/**

This is happening only on the home page. How can I remove this from my url? please help to short this out.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off store code urls in admin
admin > stores > configuration > General > Web > Add Store Code to Urls > No
run upgrade, static-content-deply and cache clean/flush commands

This comes from \Magento\Store\Model\Store::getCurrentUrl:

public function getCurrentUrl($fromStore = true)
{...

If you change the default value of the variable $fromStore from true to false, the parameter won't show up any more. You can archieve that with a before plugin as follows:

public function beforeGetCurrentUrl(Store $store, $fromStore = true)
{
return [false];
}

Comment: i only need to remove default store code, i need to use relevent store code aus for australia

Comment: Please check the latest edit